# What is the "Analog" tag supposed to be used for on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

What is the [analog](/questions/tagged/analog) tag supposed to be used for on SO?  It is lacking any description and I'm not sure what falls under it... I thought about using it for my most recent question (How do make virtual analog looking dice display using html/css and javascript), but I was hesitant with the lack of a description of what goes in there...

Answer (score 1):

Well, bearing in mind there are only 33 questions tagged with it, it's more of a descriptor than a category.

Many tags are like this, where they really have little meaning, other than as an adjective roughly describing the question topic.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Well, my point still stands. The tag could be removed, but I think it adds detail for each individual question.

Comment: Detail that should really be in the body of the question and not the tag list...

Comment: True. I suspect there are a huge amount of tags like this though. Are we saying that tags are definitive categories – if so, then it should perhaps be deleted as it's not precise enough. If not then it's fine.

Comment: Perhaps it needs to be [added to the list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012)

Comment: I think so – I've just added it.

Answer (score 1):

As Adele said -

[image]

[Burn baby burn ;)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbLqH.png)