# Is [analog] tag too broadly applied? May it deserve burnination?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

This is related to [this old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135764/what-is-the-analog-tag-supposed-to-be-used-for-on-so). Since there is no definitive answer on that thread and after more than one year the [analog](/questions/tagged/analog) tag is still used for a really broad spectrum of questions (thus it doesn't appear useful to help when searching for questions), I wonder if it deserves burnination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**  I'd stop short of burnination, but it could use some love.  Wouldn't be hard to go through 45 questions.

There are 45 questions with that tag.

At least [one of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808018/can-analog-be-used-to-create-multiple-log-files) refers to a project on GitHub called Analog.  The last update on that project was six months ago.

The rest appear to be more about

- analog signal conversion, or
- visualizations of analog items, like sweep-second clocks.

There is an [analog-digital-converter](/questions/tagged/analog-digital-converter) tag for some of the first set of questions.

(There is no [digital-analog-converter](/questions/tagged/digital-analog-converter) tag, surprisingly?)

The other questions use the [analog](/questions/tagged/analog) tag out of context of the actual problem.  It just happens to be an analog clock they want to display.  It would be like tagging something [sweater](/questions/tagged/sweater) just because I was having issues with updating the winter apparel products on my e-commerce website.

I'd suggest:

- Keeping [analog](/questions/tagged/analog) on the handful of questions that use the GitHub library of the same name.
- Doing a conversion to [analog-digital-converter](/questions/tagged/analog-digital-converter) for the appropriate questions.
- Removing the [analog](/questions/tagged/analog) tag altogether if they're just talking about displaying an analog device on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, especially for the GitHub library I didn't notice. All this make sense. Just a thing: wouldn't renaming/retagging those about the library to something more meaningful as [analog-github-libary] be better?

Comment: @LorenzoDonati If we were to vote on a name for the library I'd suggest something simple like `php-analog`. The current host of the library (Github) should not be part of the tag

Comment: @madth3 I reached the same conclusion. Since I had no response early I went for a [php-analog-package] tag, but [php-analog] could have sufficed.